# Dropbox sync api in iOS completedFirstSync remains false

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, dropbox-api

Hi i am using sync api to sync my app data to DropBox. Now i want to list and download(import) images from DBX(**i can't use core api because i already used sync api**). DBFileSystem only works after first sync complete so i added observer to DBFileSystem its called with completedFirstSync value false. This error also coming

**"[ERROR] ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_NETWORK: cfhttpbinding.c:363: CFHTTP Read Error: (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork, 2) and completedFirstSync remains false"**

In my case user link with DBX then list the images from DBX then download which one they want.
How can i acheive this using sync api?.

Comment: If you're not already using, try the latest version of the SDK, currently 2.1: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/ios This version has updated network code that may help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I am trying that.

Comment: @Madhubalan Hi, any progress here?

Comment: The first sync is depend on size of your DBX account and your file access permission. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319347/dropbox-sync-api-first-sync-in-ios