# Dropbox Sync api first Sync in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I used DropBox sync api to get sync my app data and import images from Dropbox. Now I wrote an observer to `FileSystem`. It's working fine with my account but is not working with other accounts. It's not giving any errors. `addObserver:self forPathAndChildren:[DBPath root] block:^` does not get called.

```
 if (![DBAccountManager sharedManager].linkedAccount.linked)
        {
            [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkFromController:self];
        }
        else
        {
            if(!dbFileSys)
            {
                dbFileSys = [DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem];
            }
            __weak id weakSelf = self;
            [dbFileSys addObserver:self forPathAndChildren:[DBPath root] block:^
             {
                 [weakSelf loadFiles]; //load files
             }];

        }
```

This observer called in my account. If i use other account not called.

Comment: Show a little more code than that… what does the full set-up for adding that observer look like?  Also, is "`[DBPath root]`" valid at that point?

Comment: Hi @MichaelDautermann thanks for reply. I added observer in question. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observer looks fine. I assume it's called if you make actual changes to the target Dropbox, right?

Based on your title, I assume you're expecting this to get called when you first start the app. I think that will happen the first time you link an account on a device, assuming that account has files visible to your app. (E.g. maybe you're using File type permissions and the account you link already has files of that type.) Otherwise, I wouldn't expect the observer to be called, since there were no relevant changes sync'd from the server.

Comment: Hi smarx thanks for reply. But when i use my own account observer is called every time unlink and link. It is not happen for other accounts even first time.

Comment: Do those accounts have data in them? Does your observer get called if you actually change data in that account?

Comment: Yes that account has data. I need to know when first sync complete after i have to load path, show images and folder only. That is perfectly working for my own account (development). If i try to another account completesync bit always 0. Please help me i stuck with this.

Comment: I asked two questions. You answered one. :-)

Comment: After i linked with DBX then i delete one file, Observer not called but after 2 min observer is called automatically and list all files. After this first load all changes tracked by observer. I don't know what happen. I am having 6GB data within linked DBX. Is it any problem?

Comment: I need to list files after link account as soon as possible.

Comment: Ah, then it sounds like maybe the initial sync is just taking a long time. What permissions is this app using, and how many files visible under those permissions are in the account? Also, if you don't make any changes at all, does the observer eventually fire?

Comment: After take long time. The observer fire for every changes. Can i reduce the time for first sync.

Comment: My app permissions to access DBX are images, and text files, .psd, .plist, documents and my 2 custom extension files.

Comment: Usually when I ask a question it's for a reason. :-) Without knowing how many files you're syncing the metadata for, I can't tell you how long it should take. My guess for a 2-minute sync is on the order of 100,000 files. If that's the right ballpark, then I think the performance is what you should expect.

Comment: Hi Smarx could you please help me in this dropbox sync api download images with progress bar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394820/dropbox-sync-api-for-ios-not-call-observer-when-download-images